# Auto switching uiviewcontroller objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I have a storyBoard, where I put two viewcontrollers,and designed two different keyboards on it, one is dark and other is the default, how I can auto switch these views depending on the situation, like in dark theme my keyboard look dark otherwise it shows default.
[Both vs are connected via Segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mElo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No need for two view controllers, just adjust `UIKeyboardAppearance` whenever you switch from default to dark mode or vice versa.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardappearance?language=objc

Comment: Yes thanks, I know about it, but what if buttons contain image as background. there is necessary to design two vc.

Comment: You can change a `UIButton` image in code.  And please include as much information in your original question, preferable with some images.

Comment: Sorry koen, I am new here so don't know such rules. just edited my question.

Comment: No worries, we all started here at one point. Maybe this is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask